# Java opencsv CsvToBean constructor

Tags: java, object, javabeans, opencsv

I'm trying to create a list of objects using opencsv's CsvToBean.
I have two different classes: address (address) and location (standort).
In the class location I'm trying to create an object address.

```
public class CSV {
public List<StandortAuto> readAutos() {
    CsvToBean<StandortAuto> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<StandortAuto>();

    Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    columnMapping.put("Strasse", "strasse");
    columnMapping.put("Parkplaetze", "parkplaetze");

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<StandortAuto> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<StandortAuto>();
    strategy.setType(StandortAuto.class);
    strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

    List<StandortAuto> list = null;
    CSVReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File("/Users/fabich/Projects/LeihAuto/src/com/hwz/leihauto/csv/cars.csv")),',');
        System.out.println(reader.getLinesRead());
        list = csvToBean.parse(strategy, reader);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        for (StandortAuto s : list) {
            System.out.println(s.getName());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

How can I read from a CSV file using opencsv creating a list of location objects each containing an address?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the CsvToBean is a one to one translation.  One line in the csv file becomes one object.

I had a similar situation when using openCSV,  what we did was introduce a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that was all the data in the CSV file then we created a translator class that would take the DTO object and build the Location object with Address object inside.

Hope that helps.